# Can Mathematica import uv information from 3d model?

Tags: graphics3d, textures

Question1:

Does mathematica's supported 3d file format can import uv information such that we can split the model polygons and keep the texture?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping

Question2:

If the official file format is not supported, are there any efficient ways to import such models with uv[VertexTextureCoordinates concept in Mathematica]?

I want to import a 3d model with one million or ten million polygons.

Comment: IIRC, _Mathematica_'s wavefront OBJ importer is able to read uv-coordinates--provided that they are present in the file. (However, this importer tends to be a bit slow...)